# Gmapping tf problem

Tags: navigation, mapping, gmapping, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

We are having problems with Gmapping. We are using a OMD10M-R2000 range finder and are getting odometry via RS232 from the robot. In RViz we get the following error: `No transform from [] to [map]`

[image: image description]

when we start Gmapping with following launch file we get a warning: `[ WARN] [1461833120.053747916]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.gmapping.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.`

launch file: [EDIT: old launch file](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14623478332389917.png)

```
 <launch>

<node pkg="pepperl_fuchs_r2000" type="r2000_node" name="r2000"  output="screen">
                <param name="scanner_ip" value="10.0.10.9"/>
                <param name="frame_id" value="/scan"/>
                <param name="scan_frequency" value="50"/>
                <param name="samples_per_scan" value="3600"/>
</node>



<arg name="scan_topic" value="r2000/scan" />
    <node pkg="gmapping" type="slam_gmapping" name="slam_gmapping" output="screen">

      <param name="map_update_interval" value="5.0"/>
      <param name="maxUrange" value="16.0"/>
      <param name="sigma" value="0.05"/>
      <param name="kernelSize" value="1"/>
      <param name="lstep" value="0.05"/>
      <param name="astep" value="0.05"/>
      <param name="iterations" value="5"/>
      <param name="lsigma" value="0.075"/>
      <param name="ogain" value="3.0"/>
      <param name="lskip" value="0"/>
      <param name="srr" value="0.1"/>
      <param name="srt" value="0.2"/>
      <param name="str" value="0.1"/>
      <param name="stt" value="0.2"/>
      <param name="linearUpdate" value="1.0"/>
      <param name="angularUpdate" value="0.5"/>
      <param name="temporalUpdate" value="3.0"/>
      <param name="resampleThreshold" value="0.5"/>
      <param name="particles" value="30"/>
      <param name="xmin" value="-50.0"/>
      <param name="ymin" value="-50.0"/>
      <param name="xmax" value="50.0"/>
      <param name="ymax" value="50.0"/>
      <param name="delta" value="0.05"/>
      <param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
      <param name="llsamplestep" value="0.01"/>
      <param name="lasamplerange" value="0.005"/>

<param name="odom_frame" value="odom"/>


<param name="delta" value="0.05"/>
<param name="llsamplerange" value="0.01"/>
<param name="llsamplestep" value="0.01"/>
<param name="lasamplerange" value="0.005"/>
<param name="lasamplestep" value="0.005"/>
<remap from="scan" to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>

<!-- Map size / start point -->
<param name="map_resolution" value="0.025"/>
<param name="map_size" value="2048"/>
<param name="map_start_x" value="0.5"/>
<param name="map_start_y" value="0.5" />
<param name="laser_z_min_value" value="-2.5" />
<param name="laser_z_max_value" value="3.5" />
<!-- Map update parameters -->
<param name="update_factor_free" value="0.4"/>
<param name="update_factor_occupied" value="0.7" />    
<param name="map_update_distance_thresh" value="0.2"/>
<param name="map_update_angle_thresh" value="0.06" />
<param name="pub_map_odom_transform" value="true"/>

    </node>

    <param name="robot_description" command="cat $(find urdf_agv)/src/my_agv.xml" />
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />
    <node name="tf_broadcaster" pkg="urdf_agv" type="tf_broadcaster" />     

</launch>
```

Our tf tree looks like this: `map->odom->base_link`
[EDIT: old tf tree](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/14618352031649242.png)
[image: image description]

Our rqt_graph:

[EDIT: old rqt_graph](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1461835474967964.png)

[image: image description]

Greetings,

Stijn

[EDIT]
URDF file:

```
<robot name="agv">
  <link name="base_link" />
  <link name="scan_link" />

  <joint name="joint1" type="continuous">
    <parent link="base_link"/>
    <child link="scan_link"/>
<origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
<axis xyz="0 0 0" />
  </joint>

</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233143/gmapping-tf-problem/) by [stijn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26727/stijn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-04-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you need to add your laser scanner to the tf tree.
Otherwise, `gmapping` cannot process the sensor data.

There is the Universal Robot Description Format [URDF](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/) for this.
Check out the [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials) there is everything described.

---

**EDIT**

You need to start use [`robot_state_publisher` to publish the transfrom](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher/Tutorials/Using%20the%20robot%20state%20publisher%20on%20your%20own%20robot) `base_link->scan` (I would rather rename `scan` to `laser_link` or `r2000_link` or similar).

Then, you need to add this link name to the `frame_id` of the scan. This allows the tf library to handle sensor data correctly.

---

**EDIT2**

You need to change the following line in the launch file where you start the `r2000` driver from:

```
<param name="frame_id" value="/scan"/>
```

to

```
<param name="frame_id" value="scan_link"/>
```

This is how `rviz` determines which message comes in which frame.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stijn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26727/stijn/) on 2016-04-28**:
Thanks for your answer! I made a file "my_agv.urdf" which you can view in my first post above. I don't see how this should link data from my base link to my scan data. I cant find any useful examples for making an URDF file for a 2D-laser scanner.

**Comment by [stijn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26727/stijn/) on 2016-05-04**:
Oke, i added an URDF link and started the `robot_state_publisher`. I also added a node to connect `base_link` to `scan_link`. i still get the same error in `rviz` and warning in gmapping. I'll update my opening post.

**Comment by [stijn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26727/stijn/) on 2016-05-04**:
Thanks,  but when i modified `/scan` to `scan_link` i get an error: `[slam_gmapping-2] process has died....` When i change `<arg name="scan_topic" value="r2000/scan" />` to `<arg name="scan_topic" value="scan_link" />` there is no error. But the r2000 driver is not connected to GMapping.

**Comment by [stijn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26727/stijn/) on 2016-05-04**:
Is there a way to connect them and keep `<arg name="scan_topic" value="scan_link" />` ?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-05-04**:
The topic name and the frame_id are completely seperate! `frame_id` is part of the `header` of the scan message sent over the topic with name, in your case, `r2000/scan`!

Just change the `frame_id`, keep the topic as it is. Why it is crashing, I cannot say.

**Comment by [IvanV](https://answers.ros.org/users/9801/ivanv/) on 2016-05-04**:
As comments say, you should change `frame_id`, not `scan_topic`. The point is that by setting `frame_id` to "scan", laserscans are being published in a frame reference that is not linked in the tf tree (i.e. there is no transformation for it), and thus you are getting the rviz error.

**Comment by [stijn](https://answers.ros.org/users/26727/stijn/) on 2016-05-04**:
It works! I changed `samples_per_scan` from 3600 to 2880. No more error and gmapping starts mapping. Anybody an idea how to increase this?

Thanks for all the help!